# why am I getting an expected identifier error

Tags: c, cs50

I am getting this error when I compile:

tidemantest.c:34:27: error: expected identifier
    void mergesort(pairs, 0, pair_count - 1);
                          ^
Can anyone tell me why? Thank you!

here is my minimum reproducible example (the assignment said to not change the function declaration of sort_pairs, so I put the mergesort function inside of it. the main function calls sort_pairs):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
void sort_pairs(void);
void mergesort(int a[], int s, int e);
void merge(int *a, int s, int e);

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    void mergesort(pairs, 0, pair_count - 1);
    return;
}

void mergesort(int a[], int s, int e)
{
    if (s >= e)
    {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (s + e) / 2;

    mergesort(a, s, mid);
    mergesort(a, mid + 1, e);

    merge(a, s, e);
}

void merge(int *a, int s, int e)
{
    int mid = (s + e) / 2;

    int i = s;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = s;

    int temp[100];

    while (i <= mid && j <= e)
    {
        if (preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] < preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser])
        {
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j <= e)
    {
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    for(i = s; i <= e; i++)
    {
        a[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: `void mergesort(pairs, 0, pair_count - 1);` is not a function call

Comment: should be ```mergesort(pairs, 0, pair_count - 1);``` instead of ```void mergesort(pairs, 0, pair_count - 1);```

Answer (score 1):

That error usually signifies an expected bracket or other syntax which was missing for the compiler to understand what you mean.
In here:

```
// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    void mergesort(pairs, 0, pair_count - 1);
    return;
}
```

The use of void is indicating a declaration, and the compiler thinks you have not finished the function declaration by not having braces following it. Remove the 'void' and it should work.